How to do I parse a input string in SLR(1) parser with grammar having epsilon?
This is my Grammar:
S → (S)S | ε
while my input string, which I want to parse using SLR(1):
()()
I tried making DFA with the method specified in this question, but I wasn't able to parse it :(
SLR(1) Parser and epsilon involved
This is the DFA which i made
This is my DFA, sorry for bad handwriting

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your DFA looks okay to me, but it's only the LR(0) automaton. To make the SLR(1) automaton/parser, you need the 1-symbol lookaheads for each nonterminal (i.e., S). That will tell the parser when it must reduce to S. (To get this right, your augmenting production should have an end-of-input symbol.)

Sir, can you please elaborate what you mean by "you need the 1-symbol lookaheads for each nonterminal"

In an SLR(1) parser, the set of 1-symbol lookaheads for nonterminal X is FOLLOW(X).
